# Query LINQ don't work

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have a controller method that don't work.
this is the method:

```
public ActionResult Index(DateTime? data)
{
   var servizi = (Request["servizi"] ?? "").Split(new[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Select(n => Convert.ToInt32(n)).ToArray();


    if (servizi == null || servizi.Length == 0)
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError("servizi", "Selezionare almeno un servizio");
        return View();
    }

    var dati = this.GetDbContext().mensilizzazioni.Include(x => x.operatore).Include(x => x.utente).Where(x => x.data1 == data.Value && servizi.Contains(x.id_utente_servizi));

    dati = getProfiledDatas(dati.AsQueryable<mensilizzazioni>());


    return View();
}
```

These are the errors on LINQ servizi.Contains:

- Error2 'int []' does not contain a definition for 'Contains' and the best extension method overload 'System.Linq.ParallelEnumerable.Contains  (System.Linq.ParallelQuery , TSource)'
- Error1 Argument instance: can not convert from 'int []' to 'System.Linq.ParallelQuery '

Who can help me, please. Thank you!

Comment: Are you `using System.Linq;`?

Comment: Yes I'm using System.Linq

Comment: servizi is type of interger array i guess and then you are using contains method on it.

Comment: Your line starting `var model = ` is missing a bracket. Can you fix your code - or, better, simplify it to remove any lines that aren't relevant to the question?

Comment: Actually, the line starting `var dati =` is also missing a bracket.

Comment: I have simplifyed my code

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, the only way I can replicate anything close to your problem is by removing `using System.Linq;` from the top of the controller, and you've already stated that that is present. Sorry.

Comment: Thanks anyway @AdrianWragg, I hope to find another solution

Comment: Don't try to do everything in on line. Split your code to several lines and it will be much more easy for you to debug it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**First Issue:**

You are converting the string passed to an array of `int`, then trying to run a `Contains` method on that (which does not exists on an array).

Try `ToList()` instead as it has a `Contains` method.

e.g.:

```
var servizi = (Request["servizi"] ?? "").Split(new[] { ',' },
    StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Select(n => Convert.ToInt32(n)).ToList();
```

**Second issue:**

As your member variable turns out to be an `int?` (ie. `nullable<int>`) you also need to change the second query to use the `Value` property of `id_utente_servizi`.

```
var dati = this.GetDbContext().mensilizzazioni.Include(x => x.operatore).Include(x => x.utente).Where(x => x.data1 == data.Value && servizi.Contains(x.id_utente_servizi.Value));
```

This assumes that `id_utente_servizi` is never *null*. If it can *null* be you may need to change your `Where` clause like to this: `.Where(x => x.data1 == data.Value && x.id_utente_servizi.HasValue && servizi.Contains(x.id_utente_servizi.Value))`

Comment: Thank you, but with .ToList() I have this error: -can not convert from 'int?' to 'int', The best overloaded method match for 'System.Collections.Generic.List <int> .Contains (int)' has some invalid arguments

Comment: Ah. Did not know your `id_utente_servizi` property could be null. Have updated answer to suit :)

Comment: Ohh yeah!! it was so simple ... what a fool I am :D

Comment: @Alessio De Castro: No problem. LINQ can give many weird results using both LINQ to Entities and LINQ to objects together. The solution usually involves a `ToList()` :)

Answer (score 0):

What is the type of x.id_utente_servizi?  Make sure it is an int.

If I call .Contains with the wrong argument, I get a somewhat similar error:

```
servizi.Contains("not an int");
```

'int[]' does not contain a definition for 'Contains' and the best extension method overload 'System.Linq.Queryable.Contains(System.Linq.IQueryable, TSource)' has some invalid arguments

Instance argument: cannot convert from 'int[]' to 'System.Linq.IQueryable'

Comment: The displayed error `int []' does not contain a definition for 'Contains'` is simply down to the variable `servizi` being an int array, which has no `Contains` method. There is a static `Array.contains()` but that is not as useful here.

Comment: Yes I am sure that "x.id_utente_servizi" is an INT

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie if you have System.Linq namespace then you have .Contains method on all IEnumerable<T>, including int[].  In my example, if I pass in an int, it works.  It says there's no .Contains method because I gave it the wrong type, trying to reproduce Alessio's error.

Comment: @AlessioDeCastro so it wasn't an int - it was a an int?.  However I still don't get exactly the same error as you.

Comment: @LeonidTsybert Hi, yes it was an int, now work correctly with: servizi.Contains(x.id_utente_servizi.Value)) I did put ".Value" in the contains method argument and ToList() in the var servizi

Comment: @AlessioDeCastro int's don't have  a Value property, so you are just confirming that it wasn't an int.  What you had was Nullable<int> (also known as "int?").  Call x.id_utente_servizi.GetType() to verify.  Nullable<int>.Value is an int, so you converted it from Nullable<int> to int by calling .Value.

Comment: @LeonidTsybert Yes in the DB the field id_utente_servizi is an INT that can be NULL